# How to dynamically load different Excel files containing different sheet names to SQL

Tags: sql, azure, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake

*This the generic context: Trying to copy data from excel files hosted in Azure Data Lake to Azure SQL Database
*
This is my current situation: I am using the Microsoft Azure cloud, actually I have a container in the Azure datalake that contains several Excel files, and each file has different amount of sheets with different names, I want to use an Azure Data Factory pipeline to be able to create a table in Azure SQL database for each sheet of those files, all this dynamically.

Note: Remember is not a single excel file, I have several files that I need to read from the path.

I have looked that you could use **Get metadata activity** to get the names of each file within the specific path and **lookup activity**  to specify the path that contains a csv or txt file that contains the list with the names of the sheets but I don´t know very well how to integrate both with the **for each loops** if anyone knows how to do it and could help or has another solution I would appreciate.

If you need me to expand the information of my situation to help me please let me know and I will do it right away.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have CSV file that contain excel file names and sheets name which it contains?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by performing the below aspects:

1. Use get meta data activity to get list of all excel files which you need to process
2. for each to iterate over each excel file and use the below logic stated in my blogs to iterate across all sheets within the excel :
   https://datasharkx.wordpress.com/2022/08/31/iterating-across-all-excel-sheets-dynamically-and-converting-into-csv-files-via-azure-data-factory-synapse-pipeline/
   https://datasharkx.wordpress.com/2022/09/04/iterating-across-all-excel-sheets-dynamically-and-converting-into-csv-files-via-azure-data-factory-synapse-pipeline-parallelly/

Basically you would be using the index property of Excel dataset and executing it till the point of failure.

then move over to the next excel file and its sheets

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but actually I need specify the sheet names due to I dont have to create a table for all the sheets in the file, example: I have a file with five sheets and I just going to use three of them.

Comment: I saw a solution where you create a table in sql and it contain list the sheet names and the file name but I dont have all the details about how it works so basically I need to know how you can use that table in azure datafactory to iterate dinamically and crate a table for every sheet that I specified.

Comment: Hey, a query
Is there a fixed meta data that you have? meaning the excel file name and the sheetname within that you want to load? If yes, then that is what the above approcah w.r.t SQL is. We can discuss further on this once you clarify the ask

Comment: _I have a file with five sheets and I just going to use three of them_ hoe do you decide which three? Do they have static names?